# How to use table wp_users as login?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

How do i compare user_pass in wp_users for another login?

I have tried to read through wp-includes/pluggable.php with no clue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`wp_hash_password`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password).